# Force non italic font to italics around a circle

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, creative-cloud

So I am dealing with a font that is ***not*** **Latin** which also normally does not come with an italic font option.

At first tried typing around the circle that I wanted the text to surround but I after that I quickly realized that I can not make the text italic by shearing it on it's circular path.  I then tried shearing the same text from a new horizontal textbox but then I wasn't able to copy and paste the transformed text onto the circular path I had setup earlier.

Taking the outlines and spacing each character out by hand around the circle is an option but I wanted to know if there was a better, more **efficient** and **precise** way to accomplish this.

Per request, reference photo:
[image: Reference photo for shearing and italics]

Thanks

Comment: You should add the tag of the program you use in the question

Comment: I am not sure I understand what the italics part has to do with your story. Can you make up a dummy design using a Latin (-- or, what you call "English :P) font and add it to your question?

Comment: Are you *certain* you need *italics* on a circle? Italics would reduce readability where as something such as bold or semi bold would not. Just an idea.

Comment: @Scott I am trying to mimic a certain style of lettering that is to be printed onto a wheel. I want to be able to add to the logo type that is already present without being to obvious that what I have added is not part of the original design.

Comment: @usr2564301 I am not sure if I managed to satisfy your request but I updated the question with a picture and better semantics. (removed "English")

Comment: I, personally, don't think italics are necessary.. but I can't read the language, and I surely don't understand cultural considerations.. so.. I could be wrong `:)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

[image]

A text object is outlined and sheared to 20 degrees. Then it's dragged to the Brushes collection and defined to be an artistic brush. It's applied to a piece of a circle.

The result isn't perfect, because the letters are slightly curved and also expand outwards. In theory one can compensate the expanding by distorting the letters before making the brush, but I do not know a handy way to do it.

You may need to make also a flipped and rotated copy of the brush or reverse the curve to get the wanted orientation.

Comment: Cutting at different lengths definitely gives better or worse results depending on the length of the cut but I no matter the length my last few characters are always a little warped.  Thanks for the this option!